# Leaves from binary tree

Tags: prolog

I have a binary tree like this:

```
tree(T) :-
    T = btree("classes",
              [
              btree("class1",
                    [
                    btree("thomas", [])
                    ]
              ),
              btree("class2",
                    [
                    btree("peter", []),
                    btree("liz", [])
                    ]
              ),
              btree("class3",
                    [
                    btree("anna", []),
                    btree("jack", [])
                    ]
              )]
        ).
```

I want to make a predicate tree_leaf(T, Leaf), which gives me all leaves from a binary tree. The predicate should work for every binary tree.

Comment: You should show what you've tried and ask a more specific question where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation:

```
tree_leaf(btree(X,[]),btree(X,[])).
tree_leaf( btree(_,L),Leaf):-loop(L,Leaf).

loop([X|_],Leaf):-tree_leaf(X,Leaf).
loop([_|T],Leaf):-loop(T,Leaf).
```

Example:

```
?- tree(T),tree_leaf(T,Leaf).
T = btree("classes", [btree("class1", [btree("thomas", [])]), btree("class2", [btree("peter", []), btree("liz", [])]), btree("class3", [btree("anna", []), btree("jack", [])])]),
Leaf = btree("thomas", []) ;
T = btree("classes", [btree("class1", [btree("thomas", [])]), btree("class2", [btree("peter", []), btree("liz", [])]), btree("class3", [btree("anna", []), btree("jack", [])])]),
Leaf = btree("peter", []) ;
T = btree("classes", [btree("class1", [btree("thomas", [])]), btree("class2", [btree("peter", []), btree("liz", [])]), btree("class3", [btree("anna", []), btree("jack", [])])]),
Leaf = btree("liz", []) ;
T = btree("classes", [btree("class1", [btree("thomas", [])]), btree("class2", [btree("peter", []), btree("liz", [])]), btree("class3", [btree("anna", []), btree("jack", [])])]),
Leaf = btree("anna", []) ;
T = btree("classes", [btree("class1", [btree("thomas", [])]), btree("class2", [btree("peter", []), btree("liz", [])]), btree("class3", [btree("anna", []), btree("jack", [])])]),
Leaf = btree("jack", []) ;
false.
```

As you can see I used the tree predicate in order not to type the whole tree each time so it returns also the tree T .
The above implementation stops when finds a leaf and for  each node which is not a leaf it calls `tree_leaf/2` for every child of the node.

Comment: A shorter and maybe more canonical solution might replace the second clause of `tree_leaf/2` by this: `tree_leaf(btree(_, Children), Leaf) :-
    member(T, Children),
    tree_leaf(T, Leaf).`
You then don't need your `loop/2` at all; backtracking using `member/2` will "visit" every child subtree.